# How to perform a lookup getting only the first element

Tags: mongodb, go

I have these 2 structs:

```
Category struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Name         string             `bson:"name"`
}

Book struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Name         string             `bson:"name"`
    Category     *Category          `bson:"category"`
}
```

I want to find a book aggregating its category and I execute this query

```
// lookup stage
lookupStage := bson.D{{"$lookup", bson.D{
    {"from", "category"},
    {"localField", "category"},
    {"foreignField", "_id"},
    {"as", "category"}}}}
```

With this lookup I would place the fetched category document into the book's category field.

```
// match stage (cut for simplicity, it doesn't care)
var matchStage bson.D = ...

pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    matchStage,
    lookupStage,
}

cur, err := bookCollection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)

cur.Decode(&book)
```

If I execute the query directly in MongoDB all works well, but in Go I get a null Category. I think the problem resides into the fact that the lookup returns an array but I'm trying to map it on an object.

So the question is: how can I get the first element of the array resulting by the lookup operation and place it in the book instance?

I'm using mongo official drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I execute the query directly in MongoDB all works well, but in Go I get a null Category. I think the problem resides into the fact that the lookup returns an array but I'm trying to map it on an object.

The [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage does return an array, although if this is your issue you would likely getting an error such `cannot decode array into a Category`. It maybe caused by something else, the answer below will show a working example, and hopefully will help you solve your issue as well.

There are two choices here, depending on your use case. The first is to declare `Category` as an array, i.e.

```golang
type Book struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Name     string             `bson:"name"`
    Category []*Category        `bson:"category"`
}
```

Secondly, you could utilise [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to remove the array. For example:

```golang
collection := client.Database("go").Collection("book")
lookupStage := bson.D{{"$lookup", bson.D{
    {"from", "category"},
    {"localField", "category"},
    {"foreignField", "_id"},
    {"as", "category"}}}}

unwindStage := bson.D{{"$unwind", "$category"}}
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{lookupStage, unwindStage}

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)
defer cursor.Close(context.TODO())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
cursor.Next(context.TODO())
var book Book
err = cursor.Decode(&book)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(book)
```

Having said all the above, depending on your use case you should re-consider the schema. With an assumption that a book category does not change often, you could just embed `Category` into `Book`. This would simplify a lot of querying as a book category is likely to be an important information for a book.

For more information around schema designs please see [Building With Patterns: A Summary](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary)

Comment: Sorry for the late, I can't get it working. I receive a nil category in Go, but now the query in mongodb seems to work perfectly. Do you any advice?

Comment: Your solution works, my problem was in the parsing of a previous field and it was breaking the execution, without logs.